# Refresh inbox microsoft interop outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I have the following code to login to an outlook inbox to retrieve emails.  If I don't find a certain email that I'm looking for I would like to refresh Inbox folder and try again.  Is it as simple as running this function again?

I want the equivalent of clicking on "Send/Receive" button in outlook to fetch any new emails.

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items loginEmail()
{
    //TODO.............................................
    //RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
    //session.Logon();

    //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myContacts = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

    //login
    mapiNameSpace.Logon(null, null, false, false);

    mapiNameSpace.Logon("login@mywebsite.com", "pass", false, true);


    //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items myItems = myContacts.Items;

    // Console.WriteLine("Total : ", myItems.Count);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    //  Console.Write(myInbox.Name);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items inboxItems = myInbox.Items;

    // Console.WriteLine("Total : ", inboxItems.Count);

    //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer myexp = myInbox.GetExplorer(false);

    //mapiNameSpace.Logon("Profile", Missing.Value, false, true);

    return inboxItems;
}
```

Comment: I thought these objects implement `IDisposable`, if so, you should dispose them, preferably by putting them in a `using` block

Comment: @Stefan No clue I don't see the word IDisposable in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function to fetch new mail

```
mapiNameSpace.SendAndReceive(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [NameSpace.SendAndReceive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.NameSpace.SendAndReceive) method initiates immediate delivery of all undelivered messages submitted in the current session, and immediate receipt of mail for all accounts in the current profile.

`SendAndReceive` provides the programmatic equivalent to the `Send/Receive All` command that is available when you click Tools and then Send/Receive.

If you don't need to synchronize all objects, you can use the [SyncObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobjects) collection object to select specific objects. For more information, see [NameSpace.SyncObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.syncobjects).

```
private void DirectSendAndReceiveCall(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
{
    Outlook.NameSpace ns = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    ns.SendAndReceive(false);
    if (ns != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns);
}
```

See [How To: Perform Send/Receive in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/05/outlook-send-receive-programmatically/) for more information.